# Get current system datetime by click button

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, richfaces

In JSF + RichFaces, I have an inputText and a button, How can I click in a button the datetime system will display on the inputText ? If somebody knows this, please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Date can be got using `var d=new Date()`

Comment: poor question. no trying , no research , no code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using jQuery, it sets client-side date.

```
S("#theButton").click(function{
   var currentDate = new Date();
   $("#theInput").val() = currentDate;
})
```

Comment: Thanks Raminson, I already applied your code, it's quite ok if textbox like this: <input id="textbox" type="textbox" value="ABC"></input>  </br>  But I can't do it with type of JSF: <h:inputText id="textboxJSF" value="#{myController.student}"  ===> How JQuery can understand textboxJSF ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

In the managed bean, declare this entry

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>now</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

So, in your JSF page you can use:

```
<h:outputText value="#{now}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
</h:outputText>
```

This will just the actual Date in your page.

Answer (score 0):

I applied JQuery code, and my code like following: 
`$("button:#Set").click(function () {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   $("#textbox").val(currentDate);
});`

Those code run well with type of textbox:
`<input id="textbox" type="textbox" value="Type something"></input>`

But I can't run it if I use JSF textbox:
`<h:inputText id="textboxJSF" value="#{myController.student}"`

===> How JQuery can understand textboxJSF ?  Thanks

Comment: you can find the #id of the generated input on the client-side by using sth like FF Firebug addon and set its value by jquery, for example => #JSFgeneratedInput